# PHP - Get elements from a certain index in array where one of it's elements has a certain value

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a simple way of getting a set of values inside an array when one of it's value is equal to a specified value?
For example, I retrive this array from the database where it comes with the active languages on the site: **[$active_lang]**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [code] => pt
            [idiom] => Português
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [code] => es
            [idiom] => Espanhol
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [code] => en
            [idiom] => Inglês
        )

)
```

Then I get the contents for the active languages: **[$records]**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [page_base_id] => 1
            [language] => pt
            [title] => Title pt
            [subtitle] => Subtitle pt
            [description] => Description pt
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [page_base_id] => 1
            [language] => es
            [title] => Title es
            [subtitle] => Subtitle es
            [description] => Description es
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [page_base_id] => 1
            [language] => en
            [title] => Title en
            [subtitle] => Subtitle en
            [description] => Description en
        )

)
```

What I need now is a way of echoing the right content in a `foreach` inside the array of the `$active_lang`and avoid doing a second loop to reach the right language to display inside the `$records` array. I'm currently using this code:

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <?php
  foreach ($active_lang as $lang) { ?>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_<?php echo $lang['code']; ?>">
    <div class="row-fluid ">
      <div class="span12">
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <label class="control-label">Ttile</label>
            <input id="title_1_pt" type="text" class="span12 " value="
            <?php 
            foreach($records_languages as $record){
              if($record['language']==$lang['code']){
                echo $record['title'];
              }
            }
            ?>
            " />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Is there a way of doing something like this?

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <?php
  foreach ($active_lang as $lang) { ?>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_<?php echo $lang['code']; ?>">
    <div class="row-fluid ">
      <div class="span12">
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <label class="control-label">Ttile</label>
            <input id="title_1_pt" type="text" class="span12 " value="
            <?php 
               // WHERE $records[language] == $lang['code'] ECHO THE [title] FROM THE SAME INDEX IN ARRAY
            ?>
            " />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. you should have joined at query time; 2. use `array_filter` [which would use a loop inside for sure.

Comment: 1. I need the array to be indepented so I can't do a join in the query 2. Is there no other way around instead of using a second loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new array at the very beginning:

```
$records = array();
foreach ($records_languages as $record) {
    $records[$record['language']] = $record;
}
```

and then use

```
$records[$lang['code']]['title']
```

That will save you some looping.

Comment: thank you @Mateusz Drankowski, yes I think it'll have to be something like that but I was looking for a more intuitive way of getting the information needed